# query to find primary index for a progress table (openegde V11.6)

Tags: sql, jdbc, openedge, progress-db

In the previous versions of Progress database (9.X, 10.X) the below query works fine to find the primary index of the table.

```
select "_index-name" 
  from PUB."_index" in, PUB."_file" fi 
  where fi."_file-name"='tableName' 
  and in."rowid" =
    (select"_file"."_prime-index" 
    from PUB."_file" fs 
    where fs."_file-name"='tableName');
```

Now the **rowid** has been removed on **progress v11.6**, Is there any SQL query to fetch the primary index of a progress database table through ojdbc?

Comment: Perhaps your table does not have a primary index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working in 11.6 as well. See the following query:

```
select "_index-name" from PUB."_index" idx, PUB."_file" fi where fi."_file-name"='Customer' and idx.rowid =(select"_file"."_prime-index" from PUB."_file" fs where fs."_file-name"='Customer'); 

_Index-Name
--------------------------------
CustNum
```

Comment: Thanks @Austin . i have changed in."rowid" to in.rowid and it worked fine.

Comment: With the implementation of table partitioning in OpenEdge 11.4:
     http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P58968                                   
    How can I change the above query to get the partition details to compare with ROWID?